# PHP call function in same class (of another file)

Tags: php

I have two files: **index.php** and **load.php** (*which is a class*).

I'm currently managing the languages. In the **index.php** I call the language this way:

```
include_once('load.php');
$load = new load();

include_once($load->language());
```

Then I can just simply use:

```
echo $lang['name'];
echo $lang['address']; //etc
```

My question is..how do I use this inside the class **load.php**?
I've tried so far:

```
include_once($this->language());
$lang['name'];
retrieves: Notice: Undefined variable: lang

$yo = include_once($this->language());
// retrieves $yo = bool(true) -> but I can't get info from the variable $yo
```

The function **language()** only retrieves the correct file according to the Cookie.

```
$content = 'languages/en.php';
// or
$content = 'languages/fr.php';

return $content;
```

**EDIT:** to be more clear:

**languages/en.php**

```
$lang = array();

$lang['name'] = 'Your name:';
$lang['address'] = 'Your address:';
```

**index.php**

```
include_once('load.php');
$load = new load();
include_once($load->language()); // $load->language() == 'languages/en.php';

echo $lang['name']; // works
echo $lang['address']; // works
```

**load.php**

```
public function display(){
  include_once($this->language());
  var_dump($this->lang) // returns NULL
  var_dump($this->lang['name']) // returns NULL
  // I call this function in index.php
}
```

I've tried to use:

```
return $lang
```

without success.

**Edit 2:** Looking at the answer of @Saurabh Sinha

> the thing you are trying is not right. you cannot use the variable
>   declared outside the function unless it is declared in the class. and
>   in your case too $lang variable is outside the class and the function.
>   you are able to access the same from index file just because when the
>   language function is called it gives $lang variable is index file
>   which is not a class

Which is very clear, I've join the chat with him and we conclude that the best alternative would be the define function.

```
define('name', 'Your name:')
```

Comment: try using $this->lang['name']; instead of $lang['name']; in load.php file

Comment: within the same class you need to use $this to access the properties..

Comment: where is the $lang variable initialized ?

Comment: @SaurabhSinha, I know I have to use $this in the same class. Tried your suggestion and retrieves me empty. I get no errors, but I have no output either.

Comment: you will have to make it sure that you have the value set for lang['name']; before you access it!!

Comment: @AmineMatmati in the language/en.php/fr.php file. 
`$lang = array();`

Comment: @SaurabhSinha, yes. The variable is initialized. I've used the same variable in index.php. `$lang['name']` and works.

Comment: please paste the complete code block of index, load and the language file

Comment: @user3065191: the thing you are trying is not right. you cannot use the variable declared outside the function unless it is declared in the class. and in your case too $lang variable is outside the class and the function. you are able to access the same from index file just because when the language function is called it gives $lang variable is index file which is not a class

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45702/discussion-between-saurabh-sinha-and-user3065191)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand the problem correctly this is how i would go about it.

If in your language pack you return the array of data you can assign it to a class variable.

lang file

```
return array(
  'name' => 'name',
  'address' => 'address',
);
```

load class

```
if (file_exists($path)) {
  $this->lang = (include $path);
}
```

language pack can then be accessed by `$load->lang['name'];` etc you should of course initialise the class variable for lang before you use it.

**EDIT**

if you want to be able to access the langpack from $lang[] you could always pass in that variable by reference to load method

```
public function loadLangPack(&$langRef)  //& before variable means pass a reference
{
  include_once($this->language());
  $langRef = $lang;
}
```

that would allow you to keep using $lang as you have been

index.php

```
$lang = array();
$load = new Load();
$load->loadLangPack($lang);

echo $lang['name']; 
echo $lang['address'];
```

Comment: Can't you help in my way? Or it's impossible?

Comment: i think i know what you are doing wrong but its hard to be sure with the limited code you have posted, could you include your full index.php and load.php files or at lest just the load.php file please